# ¿Es posible que al hacer un insert de varias columnas se cree una llave única para todos ellos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, insert

### ## Explicación

Bueno estoy creando un **modulo de horas extra**, las cuales se crean a partir de una selección de personas, al momento de presionar el `botón` **agregar**, se hace un `insert` estas van a una tabla temporal llamada `tmp_horasextra` luego cuando la persona a cargo de insertar las horas extra esta segura de que todo esta correcto, apreta el `boton` llamado **solicitar horas extra** el cual toma todas las columnas de la tabla temporal y las pasa a la tabla real que se llama `tbl_horaextra`, con un `id_user` respectivo para que puedan hacer insert 
simultáneos.

[image: interfaz]

### Pregunta

Ya que di la explicación correspondiente quiero saber si existe la forma de que el grupo de personas que fueron agregadas para solicitar horas extra contengan un `id` para modificar todas a partir de la selección de una, que esta sea tenga `auto_increment` ya que de otra manera existirán datos duplicados y producirán errores en la petición de nuevas horas extra.

[image: tabla_db]

Esta es la tabla que uso de horas extra, de esta manera puedo seleccionar los que contengan el mismo `id_user` para hacer la selección del `insert` que hizo una persona, pero busco tener otro id que sea para diferenciarlos, si no me explico seria algo así:

```
|id_dif|id|
|------|--|
|  1   | 1|                      
|  1   | 2|
|  1   | 3|
|  1   | 4|
|  2   | 5|
|  3   | 6|
|  3   | 7|
```

Siendo el campo `id_dif` el que diferencia los grupos de `insert`, de esta manera podría modificar el grupo entero de horas extra que fue solicitado.

**Estoy atento a cualquier tipo de ayuda, saludos!**

Comment: Yo gestionaría las horas extras en una tabla aparte, usando los ids de las personas y otro elemento como la fecha. De esa forma descargaría la otra tabla de información redundante y cualquier consulta/insert/actualización sería mucho más fácil.

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo la pregunta.. la respuesta es si, y hay muchas formas de hacerlo distintas (incluso manualmente). Yo creo que desgraciadamente la pregunta esta basada en opiniones. Ya ves que en el comentario de arriba tienes una opinion, la cual no comparto ni entiendo.

Comment: creo que estas respondiéndote a ti mismo: necesitarías 3 tablas: primero que nada una tabla de asociación: `horasextra_Asoc` en esta tablas podras poner 3 columnas, la primera seria un auto increment irrelevante, la segunda seria un ID y la tercera seria una fecha para estadística o control de cuando se creo la asociación, necesitas la temporal tal cual esta, pero a la de real `tbl_horaextra` tienes que agregarle una columna con Alter table [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541485/4717133) cuando haces el pase de la temporal a la real guardas en la tabla de asoc y en la tbl los datos.

Comment: con este esquemas guardarías 1 solo registro de asoc, y guardarías los N registro de las horas extras, puedes generar el id usando el metodo de la respuesta de Misael https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115700/46896

Comment: @Francisco , A. Cedano y gbianchi Gracias por el tiempo y las comentarios me ayudaron bastante y mostrare con una respuesta lo que hice para que me guíen y me digan si es una buena practica o no.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Manera MVC:**

Cree una consulta en el modelo:

```
  public function get_lastid(string $id_user){
    return $this->db->select('id','tbl_horasextra','id_user='.$id_user,'ORDER BY id DESC');
}
```

la cual llame desde el controlador para mostrar por la vista en un `input` oculto el valor del ultimo id de la `tbl_horasextra`.

Luego de eso solo inserto el valor del ultimo **id** de la tabla a un campo llamado `id_conjunto` de todos los usuarios ingresados.

De esta manera logre crear un `id_conjunto` con el cual puedo modificar todos los datos desde un solo `boton`.

**Gracias por el tiempo y los comentarios, si no fuera por eso nunca abría llegado a esta conclusión**

Comment: es correcto, y te felicito por pasarte a MVC y Objetos, el próximo paso es el polimorfismo.

Answer (score -1):

Buenos Dias, una manera (no la mas linda pero funciona) de hacerlo podria ser generando tu mismo el id antes de hacer el insert con la siguiente consulta:

SELECT IFNULL(max(id_dif), 0) from tbl_horaextra

y a ese valor que te retorna esa consulta le sumas 1